Is it possible to invert the f-curve?
I have this low poly character that I need to bob his head to the dialogue. I have used sound to sample and he is bobbing his head now, but the problem is that with every sound his head bobs down and clips into his chin when I need him to bob his head upwards.
How do I fix this? Is it even possible?


Select the points, then S, Y, -1?

@MarkusvonBroady Not with a curve that only contains sampled points. They have to be converted to keyframes first.

There are two ways of achieving the goal:

select the head bone, go to pose mode, pose menu > Animation > Bake action (Only selected, visual keying, overwrite current, clean curves).
Then select the relevant rotation channel, set the 2D cursor to 0,0, set the pivot point as 2D cursor, select all keyframes and press S, Y, -1, Enter.

duplicate the head bone, set the animation on the duplicate, add a copy rotation constraint on the original, targeting the duplicate, inverting the relevant axis (X in my example), Local Space to Local Space.




Option 1 only throws a lot of errors and I only get a linear ascending curve in my Blender 4.2.1, however another simple way would be to choose Channel > Samples to Keys in the Graph Editor.
